# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un array a partir de un Json?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tengo el siguiente archivo Json que me llega como respuesta y quiero hacer un Array del key `"tipodescrip"` y guardar sus valores únicamente en un Array nuevo me gustaría que no se repitiera mas de una vez algún valor , es esto posible? y si lo es como se hace? quiero aprender mas que nada

```
{
    "archivos": [
        {
            "nombre": "eir 2018, 1799.pdf",
            "id": "1595146",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "SIM38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585738",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "factura"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = {
        "archivos": [
            {
                "nombre": "eir 2018, 1799.pdf",
                "id": "1595146",
                "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
                "mime": "pdf.png",
                "tipodescrip": "COVE"
            },
            {
                "nombre": "SIM38434308002358.pdf",
                "id": "1585738",
                "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
                "mime": "pdf.png",
                "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
            },
            {
                "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
                "id": "1585739",
                "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
                "mime": "pdf.png",
                "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
            },
            {
                "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
                "id": "1585739",
                "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
                "mime": "pdf.png",
                "tipodescrip": "factura"
            }
        ]
    }
    let index = arr.archivos.length,
        current = [],
        tipoDesc = new Set()
    for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        current = arr.archivos[i]
        tipoDesc.add(current.tipodescrip)        
    }
    console.log(tipoDesc)
```

Puedes ocupar el tipo Set que es una especificación del ES2015, este tipo de array solo acepta valores unicos ademas de tener distintas funcionalidades, te adjunto un link para que puedas aprender mas de ello, ya que quieres aprender mas!!!.
http://www.etnassoft.com/2016/09/13/el-objeto-set-en-javascript-los-nuevos-arrays-en-es6-teoria-ejemplos-y-rendimiento-comparado/

Comment: Gracias estare leyendo el link que compartiste!

Comment: si te funciono? si lo resolviste asi?

Comment: Funciono de maravilla!

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es recorrer los elementos del arreglo objeto.archivos usando *forEach*.

Después no apoyamos con la funcion *indexOf* para saber si el elemento que vamos a agregar existe. Esta función nos devuelve el indice de un elemento en un arreglo, si un elemento no existe devuelve -1.

```
var objeto = {
    "archivos": [
        {
            "nombre": "eir 2018, 1799.pdf",
            "id": "1595146",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "SIM38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585738",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "factura"
        }
    ]
}

//Arreglo en el cual recopilar los valores
var array = [];

//Iterar la lista de objetos "archivos"
objeto.archivos.forEach(function(item){
  //Usar indexOf para solo agregar el valor cuando no exista
  //Cuando un elemento no existe devuelve -1
  if(array.indexOf(item.tipodescrip) == -1)
    {
        //Agregar el valor de la key "tipodescrip" al arreglo
        array.push(item.tipodescrip);
    }
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las funciones `map` y `filter` para obtener el resultado esperado

```
var arr = json.archivos
    .map(x => x.tipodescrip) // Obtiene solo tipodescrip 
    .filter((x, index, self) => self.indexOf(x) === index); // Obtiene solo elementos diferentes
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var json = {
    "archivos": [
        {
            "nombre": "eir 2018, 1799.pdf",
            "id": "1595146",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "SIM38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585738",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "Pedimento"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "ORD38434308002358.pdf",
            "id": "1585739",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "factura"
        }
    ]
}

var arr = json.archivos
    .map(x => x.tipodescrip)
    .filter((x, index, self) => self.indexOf(x) === index);


console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Una forma sencilla para realizar lo que pides sería con la función **map**, sería algo como lo siguiente:

```js
var objeto = {
    "archivos": [
        {
            "nombre": "eir 2018, 1799.pdf",
            "id": "1595146",
            "path": "http://4chan.org//archivo1.pdf",
            "mime": "pdf.png",
            "tipodescrip": "COVE"
        }
    ]
};

var arr = Object.keys(objeto).map(function(k) { return objeto[k] });

console.log(arr);
```

Puedes ver más información al respecto [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)